# how to get download link immediately upon upload the image to firebase storage?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

i have some question about using firebase storage.

I uploaded a picture using image_picker package to firebase.

At the same time I have to get the download link of the picture and use it.

I write the photo name and type correctly, but 'Object does not exist at location.' error occurs.

```
  late String img_url = '';
  XFile? _pick;
  Future getImage() async {
    _pick = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  }
  Future uploadImage() async {
    if (_pick != null) {
      Uint8List _bytes = await _pick!.readAsBytes();
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/image/beta.jpg').putData(_bytes);
      img_url = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/image/beta.jpg').getDownloadURL().toString();
      //print(FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/image/beta.jpg').getDownloadURL().toString());
    }
  }
```

- It was not the case that the file name or file type was wrong.
- I checked that photos are normally uploaded to firebase storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the download URL once the upload has completed. So you need to use `wait` on `putData`:

```
await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/image/beta.jpg').putData(_bytes);
```

And keep in mind that `getDownloadURL()` is also an asynchronous operation, so you'll want to use `await` there too.

```
img_url = (await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/image/beta.jpg').getDownloadURL()).toString();
```